# How to remove row of array which row contain value more than 10

Tags: python, numpy

```
 np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
              [ 0, 11,  0, 13,  0, 15,  0, 17, 18,  0]])
```

How to remove row of array above which row contain value more than 10?

Comment: So here you want to remove the second row only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this in a few steps. Say `a` is the original array, then:

1. first we calculate the maximum of every row;
2. then we check if that value is less than or equal to 10;
3. finally we use this for masking and thus select only rows without a value greater than 10.

Like:

```
a[a.max(axis=1) <= 10]
```

So this will return a copy of the original array that contains only rows that contain no values greater than 10.

Answer (score 0):

**@Quanter**, try this.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> arr = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
...               [ 0, 11,  0, 13,  0, 15,  0, 17, 18,  0]])
>>>
>>> a = [a for a in arr if not np.max(a) > 10]
>>>
>>> a
[array([0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
>>>
```